# HiveServer2 - Hue connections

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

We have hive running in CDH 5.4.5.

In the last few months, we suffer from a lot of "silent crashes" - queries are getting stucked and workflows in oozie run much slower than usual till we reset HS2 and everything runs normally.

Our main thesis was that there are too many connections to HS2, causing a certain overhead and eventually HS2 is crashing.

After monitoring the number of connections using netstat, we saw that the number of connections when the problem occured was about 250 instead of 30. In addition, we saw that 70% percent of the connections were  Hue's.
When we compared the number of hue connections to number of queries that were done, we didn't see any correlation (oozie workflows are not identified as Hue connection so the only possible activity for HS2 connections is Hive/Impala queries).

So, we have a question about the Hue connections. On which actions / events does the Hue open a new connection to Hiveserver2?

Every time a query window is opened?

Every time a query is launched?

Comment: At a previous client site I witnessed that HS2 MTBF *(Mean Time Between Failures)* was about 36 hrs. So we set up a H.A. setup based on ZooKeeper, with manual switch of "primary" HS2 instance every 24 hrs and forced restart of the "secondary" a few hours later. Piece of crap  »:-(

Comment: Ah, and we had banned Hue altogether -- because it is a lousy piece of shoftware (vomiting torrents of Python errors in server logs) and also because it is historically a Cloudera creature and does not fit very well in other distros.

Comment: Side note: Hue also connects directly to the Hive Metastore (navigation in databases and tables). And a busy Metastore is a possible root cause for your trouble.

Comment: On the other hand, the *"queries getting stuck"* because the query processing engine had crashed and burned (**OOM**) but the Thrift server was still alive and accepting connections, is something that rings a bell. Not only we restarted HS2 every day, but we also ran a "canary" every 15 min to check the primary HS2 was responding (i.e. accepting *and* processing new connections).

Comment: Hue has one connection to HS2 by user, and HS2 might create on Zookeeper connection by query when these ones are not closed: http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-hive-and-impala-queries-life-cycle/

Comment: PS, to be more constructive than above comments: Hue is more and more popular and scalable, feel free to check the blog for the latest on SQL and performances gethue.com/blog/

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Romain - after some tries, we saw that every query  submitted creates a connection to HS2. Does it make sense? Furthermore, what else can create connections by Hue to HS2 besides queries ? (Maybe Oozie workflows?). Thanks in advance.